Bison parsing won't terminate properly, although all the parsing was done correctly (unexpected x, expecting $end)
I get this error: Error: syntax error, unexpected (something), expecting $end, where (something) stands for the last token in the file. My grammar is large so I can't show it here, but here are some segments I think are of notice:
program :   command_list END
            {
            }
        ;

command_list :  command_list newlines command
                {
                    Command command = $3;
                    std::vector<Command> &list = $1;
                    list.push_back(command);
                    $$ = list;
                }
                | command
                {
                    Command command = $1;
                    $$ = std::vector<Command>();
                    $$.push_back(command);
                };

newlines : newlines NEWLINE | NEWLINE;

I have a
    <<EOF>>     { return yyterminate(); }

rule in the flex file, that I thought caused this, but that was not the case.

You shouldn't use END anywhere unless you know what you're doing and have a very good reason. $end is implied at the end of the main production and you're not supposed to add it explicitly. Just remove the END from program and the whole line <<EOF>>     { return yyterminate(); }. It should work.

As suggested here: Make Bison accept an alternative EOF token, adding %token END 0 "end"; to tokens in .y file solves the issue. My .y file had a %token END "end"; line, but without the 0 bison got confused.

Please, fix the link
